Why does the Magisterium fear knowledge of the secret of the rose oil?
As of the end of The Secret Commonwealth, the second volume of The Book of Dust, which is the prequel and sequel series to His Dark Materials, the nature of the rose oil appears to be something very much like the Amber Spyglass that was constructed in the homonymous novel:

 it allows one to see the aura of Dust around humans (or other creatures), and the bond of Dust going between them and their daemons.

Now, the Magisterium, which is basically an alternate-universe Catholic Church, finds this deeply disturbing, such that it will go to any extent to suppress this information. The priest Delamare even says that it undermines their entire doctrine.
Except, why? All it basically seems to give is a physical proof of the reality of daemons, i.e. the soul, and their connection to humans—not that they really need much more evidence of that, what with daemons in their world being common knowledge, visible, accompanying nearly every human being, and intimately tied to their continued existence. The real-world Catholic Church would probably kill to publicize such information, not to suppress it, and the doctrine of the Magisterium seems very similar.1 I do recall some statement from His Dark Materials that the Magisterium considers Dust to be evidence of original sin, but that original sin would stain both a person and their soul hardly seems doctrinally threatening.

1: When His Dark Materials first came out, they were perceived as very anti-religious, and Pullman might even have said something to this effect; ironically, though, they portray a world where the existence of souls, an afterlife, angels, angelic scriptural inspiration, and the Devil and God (albeit different from their traditional religious portrayals),  among other things, is objective and relatively easily demonstrated scientific fact.

Dust represents the ability of adults to think for themselves, make choices about their life, and question authority. The Magisterium does not want their authority questioned, so they need everyone to consider the existence of Dust heresy. And that is why they supported the Intercision experiments of the General Oblation Board. This would make people docile, like some of the staff at the Svalbard facility. Mrs. Coulter explains to Lyra how problematical Dust is; what she avoids saying is that it's specifically a problem for the Magisterium.
So, anything that confirms the existence of Dust is something the Magisterium doesn't want. Lord Asriel's photo emulsion, or the rose oil. Or if it existed in Lyra's world, the oil used by the mulefa.

Yes, I know I didn't bother to put in specific quotes.

OK, that does make sense as the explanation in the series. I do recall something along those lines. Although I still find it a little puzzling. Basically, the Magisterium seem to be against the notion that anyone would infer that they had free will and use that to question their authority (since as you say, that is basically what Dust represents). Although the nature of prophecy seems to complicate that question in the story, Dust does basically seem to represent free will and consciousness in a scientific form.

However, in the real world, the Catholic Church managed to be quite controlling for many centuries while explicitly endorsing the doctrine of free will. While they definitely want to maintain their religious and political power and authority (and even more so a few centuries back), they would probably be thrilled to have a scientific proof of "God-given free will." So does the Magisterium not have this doctrine (perhaps as a result of Calvinist predestination pushing it out?)

Since preaching that everyone can choose between good and evil while trying to suppress evidence that they could choose between good and evil would seem...counterproductive, to say the least.

The magisterium had no pope since John Calvin abdicated and that old Eastern Bishop is appointed in the Secret Commonwealth. There are many agencies within it with conflicting theologies, purposes, and scopes. The actions of the magisterium could be the result of internal coalition plays vs. a single unified theology and goals.

Sure, but why does even one person with authority there think it's a threat?

Because he is a religious nutter
